# how to set app name for SparkR?

Tags: sparkr

Does any one know how to set the application name for a SparkR job? I can not find the relevant api at all. The sample code shows the availability of spark after loading the SparkR lib.

```r
library(SparkR)
sparkR.session()
```

after that you can make the `spark.lapply(...)` call. How do you set the app name using the spark variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application name is set with the `appName` argument of `sparkR.session()`; from the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/R/sparkR.session.html):

```r
sparkR.session(master = "", appName = "SparkR",
  sparkHome = Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), sparkConfig = list(),
  sparkJars = "", sparkPackages = "", enableHiveSupport = TRUE, ...)
```

Comment: But the sample code never used sparkR.session. It simply start referencing spark, and called lapply on it. When I add the statement sparkR.session(appName = "SomeOtherName"), it still shows SparkR as the app name.

Comment: @bhomass that's because probably you run some interactive application (RStudio or SparkR shell); `appName` is there for mainly applications you run with `spark-submit`

Comment: strange. I edited my response, but the old comment still shows up. I got it work already. thanks for the advice.